# The value for the useBean class attribute oracle.jsp.jml.JmlString is invalid

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I am trying to create a web server application based on the documentation from oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/acase.htm#CIABCIHF

I choose to use the .jsp file version with Apache Tomcat.
For this, I installed Apache Tomcat, i created a jsp file and saved it in webapps folder and tried to call it from a browser but I have the above error message.

Can someone guide me how to do it work fine?

BTW, I have no skill on jsp.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the class `JmlString` exists in the package `oracle.jsp.jml`. If you are housing the class in a different package, you need to change the JSP to reflect the appropriate path.
2. Make sure the class `JmlString` has a no-arg public constructor. Without this, your `userBean` cannot be instantiated by the container.

Comment: I think I don't have the JmlString class. I was searching for it but didn't find any result.

Comment: Can I find it somewhere, maybe at Oracle ...?

Comment: Actually, this class is in Oracle JSP appliation. You need to download ojsp.jar and keep it in your classpath. Refer to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97339_01/doc/jsp.106/devguide/install.htm) documentation.

Comment: I found the ojsp.jar somewhere in Oracle DB. Can you tell me where should I put, please?